# SOAP - Operation Timed Out - Rule out my server

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I am using SOAP in C# .Net 3.5 to consume a web service, from a video game company.  I am having lots of SOAP Exceptions with the error "Operation Timed Out"

While one process is timing out, others fly by with no problems. I would like to rule out a problem on my end, but I have no idea where to begin.  My timeout is 5 minutes.  For every 5,000 requests, maybe 500 fail.

Anyone have some advice for diagnosing web services failures?  The web service owner will probably give no support to helping me on this, as it's a free service.

Thanks

Comment: You could check whether you're using the SOAP correctly, like for example, do you create the ServiceClass in a using() statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had to do a lot of debugging connecting to a SOAP Service using PHP and timeouts are the worst problem. Normally the problem is the 'client' doesn't have a high enough timeout and bombs after something like 30s.

I test making the calls using SoapUI. I keep using a higher client-side timeout using that until I find something that works. Once I find that out I use the newly found time to my client and re-test.

Your only solution may be to make sure your 'clients' have a high enough timeout that will work for everything. 5 minutes should be fine for most of your server-side timeouts.

Comment: Downloaded SoapUI, will run it when things start timing out.

Answer (score 1):

OK this is a huge question and there is a lot that it could be.

Have you tackled HTTP two connection limit? http://madskristensen.net/post/Optimize-HTTP-requests-and-web-service-calls.aspx

Have you got enough IO threads to cater for the load? Use the performance monitoring to check this for your App Pool - I think there is a IO threads counter.  A quick google turned this up - http://www.guidanceshare.com/wiki/ASP.NET_2.0_Performance_Guidelines_-_Threading

Are you exhausting your bandwidth? Use performance monitoring again to check the usage of your network card.

This is a really hard subject to broach textually, as it so dependent on environment but I hop these might help.

This also looks interesting - http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/how-to-tune-the-machineconfig-file-on-the-aspnet-platform/

Comment: Thanks, will check out your links and report back